# Python Twisted Socket Server

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, lag

I've been using this Twisted Python TCP socket server for quite a while now and it's now starting to really get to me. My issue is that I have 350+ (give or take depending on the day and hour) clients on at once and sometimes I'll have major lag. By lag I mean sometimes when in a "room" (it's an avatar chat basically, users have inventories, friends, houses, etc etc) with any amount of users (usually like 10+ users in the room does it) there will usually be 2-5 second "freezes" every minute or so. By freezes I mean no packets are sent and nobody can see anyone move their character, talk, or anything. After it unfreezes it's like all the packets just send at once and you see everyone's messages and stuff.

My socket sever was based off this: https://github.com/jesstess/twisted-network-programming-essentials-examples/blob/master/Chapter11-Testing/chatserver.py

I'm wondering what I can do to prevent lag. I was thinking multi-threading, but how would I go about doing that in something such as the above example? The most clients I ever had online was 451 a few weeks ago, but I don't think that'll happen anytime soon.

If you're confused about my question - basically I'm asking how to make the server better handle ~350 clients and prevent lag/freezes to all clients in a room.

Edit: Unlike that example, I have added this at the bottom:

```
ServerCL = GameServer(sys.argv[1])
reactor.listenTCP(int(config.get('GameServer1_' + str(sys.argv[1]), 'port')), ServerCL)
reactor.listenTCP(int(config.get('GameServer2_' + str(sys.argv[1]), 'port')), ServerCL)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: I believe twisted is *already* multithreaded under the hood, so I am not sure you are going to get much from that (please feel free to check...it has been a while since I played with it).  Isolating "why" it is slow is definitely the right approach...

Comment: twisted is not threaded, but event based. This means everything runs within the same thread and if an event handler blocks or takes too long all connections will suffer.

Comment: Is it possible that maybe not using Twisted as my socket server base would make it better? Maybe using the normal socket lib?

Comment: Without knowing the cause there's no way to predict what any particular change will do.  Perhaps the problem you're encountering is because some code is blocking the event loop somewhere: in that case, switching to a multi-threaded server *could* eliminate the problem.  On the other hand, maybe it's blocking in a way that would still affect a multi-threaded server.  And maybe the problem is caused by something else entirely, like an object leak that causes the garbage collector to take a long time to run.  A problem such as this would not be fixed by switching to a multi-threaded server.

Comment: Ultimately, if you want to know what *change* will actually be a *fix* you have to understand the cause of the problem.  Producing (and sharing) a minimal example that demonstrates the problem (<http://sscce.org>) would be a good step towards that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "freezes" could be happening for a variety of reasons.  Most likely this is not something within Twisted itself, but something within your application which is taking that 2-5 seconds and preventing the server from doing anything else.

It sounds like you've got a large, complex application, so rather than guessing at what it might be, I suggest you use a tool like [`twisted_hang`](https://github.com/ggreer/twisted_hang) to identify where your application is getting stuck; that should give you some idea of what you could change.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into it and try it.

Comment: Just wondering, but have you ever used it before? I'm using it now and I'm getting a ton of output of just stuff like this: [image](http://i.imgur.com/y9COLES.png). I'm using the defaults they have in their github: 

  `watcher = HangWatcher(0.1, 0.5)
  watcher.start()`

Comment: Anyone have any ideas..?

Comment: What that output is telling you is that `cursor.execute` is what's blocking your program.  Which is not surprising!  Executing some SQL is a blocking network request to an external system, your database, which can be quite slow.  You need to do non-blocking database I/O; take a look at Twisted's built-in `twisted.enterprise.adbapi` http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/rdbms.html , `adbapi2` from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twextpy , or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alchimia .